# Carousel issue in WordPress (Storefront theme)

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, woocommerce, swiper.js

I'm using Woocommerce Storefront theme for my shop and my goal is to add simple, drag free carousel with images. I tried to do that with `Swiper` library and when I tested my code in pure html, css and js, everything worked fine. However, when I put my code in Storefront hooks in `functions.php`, carousel didn't work. I tried another carousel library - `Embla`, but the issue remains the same. Carousel is displayed properly, but it's impossible to move the slides (slides are dragging during click and movemouse events, but it bounce back to starting position after realesing mouse click or touch on mobile).

You can check the issue live, here (carousel under orange button, works only on viewport with less than 768px):

https://skylo-test1.pl

I suspect that the reason could be some hidden CSS or JS inside Storefront theme, but I comment out all CSS from `style.css` file and it doesn't fix the issue.

I also tried to disable all plugins, but it doesn't work as well.

Here's my html:

```
 <div class="carousel__content swiper-container">
            <div class="carousel__embla swiper-wrapper">
                <a class="carousel__item" href=".">
                    <img class="carousel__item__img" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/assets/images/alcanta/slider-looked.png'; ?>" alt="carousel-item" />
                </a>

                <a class="carousel__item" href=".">
                    <img class="carousel__item__img" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/assets/images/alcanta/slider-looked.png'; ?>" alt="carousel-item" />
                </a>

                <a class="carousel__item" href=".">
                    <img class="carousel__item__img" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/assets/images/alcanta/slider-looked.png'; ?>" alt="carousel-item" />
                </a>

                <a class="carousel__item" href=".">
                    <img class="carousel__item__img" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/assets/images/alcanta/slider-looked.png'; ?>" alt="carousel-item" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel__content {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel__embla {
    display: flex;
}

.carousel__item {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    flex: auto;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Javascript when I tried to use Swiper:

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
   freeMode: true,
   slidesPerView: 2
});
```

Javascript when I tried to use Embla:

```
const emblaContainer = document.querySelector(".carousel__content");
const emblaOptions = {
    dragFree: true,
    containScroll: "trimSnaps"
};

const embla = EmblaCarousel(emblaContainer, emblaOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the Embla opt-in method named `embla.clickAllowed()`. I don't know if you're using the VanillaJS or ReactJS version of Embla. Anyhow, example usage looks something along these lines:

##### VanillaJS

```
const onSlideClick = (index) => {
  if (!embla.clickAllowed()) return
  
  // Embla says the pointer interaction was a static click, and not a drag move.
  // Do your magic here...
}
```

```
embla.slideNodes().forEach((slide, index) => {
  slide.addEventListener('click', () => onSlideClick(index), false)
})
```

##### ReactJS

```
const onSlideClick = useCallback((index) => {
  if (!embla || !embla.clickAllowed()) return

  // Embla says the pointer interaction was a static click, and not a drag move.
  // Do your magic here...
}, [embla])
```

```
<div className="embla__container">
  {slides.map((slide, index) => {
    <div className="embla__slide" onClick={() => onSlideClick(index)}>
      ...
    </div>
  })}
</div>
```

##### How it works under the hood

If the pointer is **touch**, Embla will:

- Prevent a click when the gesture is a drag move.
- Prevent clicks when the carousel is clicked during scroll.

If the pointer is **mouse**, Embla will:

- Prevent a click when the gesture is a drag move.
- Not prevent clicks when the carousel is clicked during scroll.

The reason behind this design choice is that touch pointers scroll the document. And when the document is natively scrolling on touch devices, it prevents clicks until the user stops the scrolling and clicks again when it's settled.

But mouse pointers are not used to scroll the document, unless you're dragging the scrollbar. And if you're dragging the scroll bar, it will prevent you from accidentally clicking anything on the webpage anyway, because the pointer is within the scroll bar area. So the assumption here is that we can be more certain that a click with a mouse pointer is intentional.

**Links**

- API reference for `embla.clickAllowed()` [here](https://www.embla-carousel.com/api/methods/#clickallowed).
- A guide on how to implement click events with Embla on the documentation website [here](https://www.embla-carousel.com/guides/click-events/).